# segmentation fault after taking in elements of both matrices

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

If I run program, it lets me input 3 integers n,m,p and elements of matrices. n is rows, m and p are columns. However, it says segmentation error soon after I input the final element, like so;

```
4
3
2

Enter element matrix 1[0][0]: 3
Enter element matrix 1[0][1]: 9
Enter element matrix 1[0][2]: 3

Enter element matrix 1[1][0]: 2
Enter element matrix 1[1][1]: 7
Enter element matrix 1[1][2]: 9

Enter element matrix 1[2][0]: 0
Enter element matrix 1[2][1]: 5
Enter element matrix 1[2][2]: 8

Enter element matrix 1[3][0]: 5
Enter element matrix 1[3][1]: 4
Enter element matrix 1[3][2]: 3

Enter element matrix 2[0][0]: 8
Enter element matrix 2[0][1]: 3

Enter element matrix 2[1][0]: 9
Enter element matrix 2[1][1]: 7

Enter element matrix 2[2][0]: 8
Enter element matrix 2[2][1]: 5

Segmentation fault
```

```
    matrix1 = (int**) malloc(row1 * sizeof(int*));

//read elements of 1st matrix
for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
    matrix1[i] = (int*) malloc(col1 * sizeof (int));
    for (j = 0; j < col1; j++) {
      printf("\nEnter element matrix 1[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
    }
}

matrix2 = (int**) malloc(row2 * sizeof (int*));

//read elements of 2nd matrix
for (i = 0; i < row2; i++) {
    matrix2[i] = (int*) malloc(col2 * sizeof (int));
    for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
      printf("\nEnter element matrix 2[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]);
    }
}
//memory allocation of no. of cols in matrix
mtxProduct = (int**) malloc(row1 * sizeof (int*));

//memory allocation of no. of cols in matrix
for (i = 0; i < col2; i++) {
    mtxProduct[i] = (int*) malloc(col2 * sizeof (int));
}
//multiplication
for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
        mtxProduct[i][j] = 0;
        for (e = 0; e < row2; e++) {
            mtxProduct[i][j] +=(matrix1[i][e] * matrix2[e][j]);
        }
    }
}
//print matrix product
for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
        printf("%d ", mtxProduct[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < col2; i++) {
   mtxProduct[i] = (int*) malloc(col2 * sizeof (int));
}
```

should be row1 instead of col2 within the head of the for loop. Segmentation fault means that you try to access a place in memory which you should not try to access. Hence you should look for lines of code where you access uninitialized pointers or array elements that are out of bounds.

Comment: Sorted. Thank you very much JohnB